# Copy values of cells from a DataGridView column to an ArrayList

Tags: vb.net, arraylist, datagridview

I am using a DataGridView with an ArrayList.  When a user clicks a button, I want the values of the first column (there will be 4 columns total, each having its own ArrayList) of the DataGridView to be written to an ArrayList.  I am using an ArrayList because the number of rows in the Datagridview can vary, so the array size cannot be static.  The code that I have written, actually searched and got help online with is "almost" working.  It will write the values of the first column to the arraylist, but I have to click on the button twice.  It will only update the ArrayList on the second click of my button.  What needs to change with my code?  Thanks from a newbie!

```
Private Sub btnPrintArray_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrintArray.Click

    Dim message = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lftMtrAccelRates.ToArray())
    lftMtrAccelRates.Clear() 'clears ArrayList
    rchTxtBox.Clear() 'Clears rich text box that has array element values in it
    For Each d In LftMtr_Data_Grid.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)()
        Dim num As Integer
        If Int32.TryParse(d.Cells(0).Value, num) Then
            lftMtrAccelRates.Add(num)
        End If
    Next
    rchTxtBox.Text = message
End Sub`
```

Comment: Why not a `List(Of T)` instead of an `ArrayList`?

Comment: Now using List(Of T) instead of ArrayList.  Working the same so should be good.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility:

```
Private values As New List(Of Integer)

Private Sub btnPrintArray_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrintArray.Click
    values.Clear()
    Dim num As Integer
    For Each d As DataGridViewRow In LftMtr_Data_Grid.Rows
        If Int32.TryParse(d.Cells(0).Value, num) Then
            values.Add(num)
        End If
    Next
    rchTxtBox.Lines = values.ConvertAll(Function(x) x.ToString).ToArray
End Sub
```